# How to convert Reader to InputStream in java

Tags: java, memory-management, inputstream, reader

I need to convert a Reader object into InputStream. My solution right now is below. But my concern is since this will handle big chunks of data, it will increase the memory usage drastically.

```
private static InputStream getInputStream(final Reader reader) {
   char[] buffer = new char[10240];
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   int charCount;
   try {
      while ((charCount = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
         builder.append(buffer, 0, charCount);
      }
      reader.close();
   } catch (final IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return new ByteArrayInputStream(builder.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

Since I use StringBuilder this will keep the full content of the reader object in memory. I want to avoid this. Is there a way I can pipe Reader object? Any help regarding this highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you need the `InputStream` for? If you want to write the data to somewhere, maybe there is no need to have an intermediate `InputStream`.

Comment: It's often easier to get not an InputStream, but an output stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Apache Commons IO library, you can do this conversion in one line:

```
//import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReaderInputStream;

    
    InputStream inputStream = new ReaderInputStream(reader, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

You can read the documentaton for this Class at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReaderInputStream.html

It might be worth trying this to see if it solves the memory issue too.

Comment: I would never have thought Apache covered this usage too. Would have saved me the effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. This worked marvelously for me. Good to know commons.io has inbuild functionality for this.

Answer (score 1):

First: a rare requirement, often it is the other way around, or there is a FileChannel, so one can use a ByteBuffer.

A PipedInputStream would be possible, starting a PipedOutputStream in a second thread. However that is unneeded.

A Reader gives chars. Unicode *code points* are derived from either one or two chars (the latter a surrogate pair).

```
/**
 * Reader for an InputSteam of UTF-8 text bytes.
 */
public class ReaderInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final Reader reader;
    private boolean eof;
    private int byteCount;
    private byte[] bytes = new byte[6];

    public ReaderInputStream(Reader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (byteCount > 0) {
            int c = bytes[0];
            --byteCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; ++i) {
                bytes[i] = bytes[i + 1];
            }
            return c;
        }
        if (eof) {
            return -1;
        }

        int c = reader.read();
        if (c == -1) {
            eof = true;
            return -1;
        }
        char ch = (char) c;
        String s;
        if (Character.isHighSurrogate(ch)) {
            c = reader.read();
            if (c == -1) {
                // Error, low surrogate expected.
                eof = true;
                //return -1;
                throw new IOException("Expected a low surrogate char i.o. EOF");
            }
            char ch2 = (char) c;
            if (!Character.isLowSurrogate(ch2)) {
                throw new IOException("Expected a low surrogate char");
            }
            s = new String(new char [] {ch, ch2});
        } else {
            s = Character.toString(ch);
        }
        byte[] bs = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byteCount = bs.length;
        System.arraycopy(bs, 0, bytes, 0, byteCount);
        return read();
    }
}

        Path source = Paths.get("...");
        Path target = Paths.get("...");
        try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(source, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                InputStream in = new ReaderInputStream(reader)) {
            Files.copy(in, target);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any possibility with pure JDK means. The [StringBufferInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html) is deprecated because it does not convert characters into bytes properly.
If Guava library is available in the project, the internal [ReaderInputStream](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/io/ReaderInputStream.java) can be used via:

```
public InputStream asInputStream(Reader reader, Charset charset) throws IOException {
    return new CharSource() {
        @Override public Reader openStream() {
            return reader;
        }
    }.asByteSource(charset).openStream();
}
```

Under the hood the *Reader* is wrapped into the *InputStream* mentioned in the beginning.